# Java out patterns

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to get this output using nested loops:

[image]

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the @ signs to increment by +2 each time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class PrintPatterns { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        pattern1();
    }

    private static void pattern1() { 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 2); { 
                System.out.print("@ ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(". ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < 10 - i; j++) {
                System.out.print("x ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Work it out the logic on paper first before committing it to code. Do this and the algorithm should come to you.

Comment: You need to format your code better. Also you're short-circuiting at least one for loops by placing `;` semicolons where they don't belong: `for(int j = 0; j < 10; j+=2); { `.  Take care, don't be sloppy, and if you format things correctly, you'd see this.

Comment: 2*row should equal the number of @.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 2); { 
    System.out.print("@ ");
}
```

Try:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i; j += 1) { 
    System.out.print("@ ");
}
```

Comment: Semicolon kills the loop prematurely.

Comment: No worries, I think that was his chief problem anyway. Hard to debug a logical error before figuring out the others.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want:

```
private static void pattern1() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int ats = 2; ats <= 10; ats += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ats; j++) {
            stringBuilder.append("@ ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append(". . ");
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10 - ats; j++) {
            stringBuilder.append("x ");
        }
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

One mistake you did in your code is that you put a `;` after your for loop, this will end the loop right there.

Also do not use `System.out.println()` in loops. As using IO will slow down your application. Use `StringBuilder` to build strings and then output all at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintPatterns
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        pattern1();
    }

    private static void pattern1()
    { 
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {

            for(int j = 1; j < i+2; j++)
            { 
                System.out.print("@ ");
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(". ");
            }

            for(int k = 10-i; k > 0; k--)
            {
                System.out.print("x ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Instead of only giving only code, please provide some explanation so that your answer is more useful.